# How to format files on pre-commit hook in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

To save time, I want to run an auto-formatter on Kotlin files. It is okay if it just formats whitespace. I want to set it up to run automatically on git-commit hook to be IDE agnostic. We are using Maven. Anyone knows of a maven plugin that does this?

For example there are [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) for the JS / web ecosystem, [gofmt](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/gofmt) for Go, [Black](https://pypi.org/project/black/) for Python and [CSharpier](https://csharpier.com/) for C#. The plugin [prettier-plugin-kotlin](https://github.com/Angry-Potato/prettier-plugin-kotlin) mentioned on the Prettier website seems unsuitable for production. And it would be nice to avoid installing another package manager just to install a formatter.

Comment: There is `Detekt` which is a linter for kotlin. You can add a pre-commit hook as described here https://detekt.dev/docs/gettingstarted/git-pre-commit-hook/

Comment: @spyrospal Nice! Detekt had a lot of extra stuff, but the formatting seems to come from ktlint [which can run on pre-commit](https://pinterest.github.io/ktlint/0.50.0/install/cli/#git-hooks). Thanks!

Comment: You may want to take a look at pre-commit hook tool. There is ton of scripts for it. See this article: https://stackoverflow.com/at/71270196/1235698 or search on web

Answer (score 1):

Install [ktlint](https://github.com/z3d1k/ktlint-maven-plugin) and set pre-commit hook:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

echo "Running git pre-commit hook"

# Gather the staged files - to make sure changes are saved only for these files.
stagedFiles=$(git diff --staged --name-only)

mvn ktlint:format

STATUS=$?

# return 1 exit code if running checks fails
if [ "$STATUS" = 0 ] ; then
    echo "Static analysis found no problems."
    # Add staged file changes to git
    for file in $stagedFiles; do
      if test -f "$file"; then
        git add $file
      fi
    done
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```